# How to get codepoint of particular WCHAR character?

Tags: c++, wchar-t

For example I need `codepoint` of 5th character here, that is `ð`

```
const WCHAR* mystring = L"Þátíð";
```

I know that it has code point : `U+00F0` - but how to get this integer using c++ ?

Comment: wchar_t is a compiler specific type, WCHAR indicates Windows (wchar_t==WCHAR==UCS2/UTF16LE) If you want portability you need to change WCHAR to wchar_t. If this is Windows only you should tag it with a windows tag...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const WCHAR myString[] = L"Þátíð";
size_t myStringLength = 0;
if(SUCCEEDED(StringCchLengthW(myString, STRSAFE_MAX_CCH, &myStringLength))
{
    LPCWSTR myStringIterator = myString;
    for(size_t sz = 0; sz < myStringLength; ++sz)
    {
        unsigned int mySuperSecretUnicodeCharacter = *myStringIterator;
        LPCWSTR myNextIterator = CharNext(myStringIterator);
        std::vector<unsigned int> diacriticsOfMySuperSecretUnicodeCharacter(myStringIterator+1, myNextIterator);
        myStringIterator = myNextIterator;
    }
}
```

Edit 1: made it actually work

Edit 2: made it actually look for all codepoints

Comment: Okay, I give up... This: U+0061 U+0301 U+0302 U+0303 U+0304 (a´^~¯) cannot be hold by any "normal" type. Assuming that you can never know the real code point.

Comment: A Unicode code point (a value in the Unicode codespace) will fit in 32bit but what a user calls a "character" might not fit...

Answer (score 2):

WCHAR in Windows 2000 and later is UTF-16LE so it is not necessarily safe to access a specific character in a string by index. You should use something like [CharNext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647469%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to walk the string to get correct handling of surrogate pairs and combining characters/diacritics.

In this specific example Forgottn's answer depends on the compiler emitting precomposed versions of the `á` and `í` characters... (This is probably true for most Windows compilers, porting to Mac OS is probably problematic)